# Why use HTML5 in a responsive web design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I see HTML5 mentioned often in discussions of responsive web design.  Although I'm not sure why someone would want to use HTML5 for a simple responsive web design.

Are either of these statements untrue?

- HTML5 is not needed for responsive web design
- CSS and media queries will do the job fine

If you have a text only website, what is the benefit to using HTML5 for your responsive web design?  It can't replace media queries.  CSS works fine for fluid grids and images.

Here's some of what I'm referring to:

[http://www.amazon.com/Responsive-Web-Design-HTML5-CSS3/dp/1849693188/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1383016419&sr=8-2&keywords=responsive+web+design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849693188)

[http://www.amazon.com/HTML5-CSS3-Responsive-Design-Cookbook/dp/184969544X/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1383016419&sr=8-7&keywords=responsive+web+design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184969544X)

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Modern-Web-Multi-Device-Development/dp/1593274874/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1383016419&sr=8-12&keywords=responsive+web+design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593274874)

Comment: When you say "HTML5", what do you mean specifically?  HTML5 is just the latest version of the HTML specification and it includes all of the latest HTML.  I suspect you're really asking about certain features that may have been added in HTML5, but your question would be more meaningful if you named those actual features.

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with responsive designs, it's just for semantics.. it's all CSS, yea now if you ask why use CSS3 for responsive design than it's another question

Comment: @jfriend00: I've updated the post to include a few books relevant to the question.  @ mrAlien: Thanks. What I was assuming was correct.

Comment: Those book titles just says that the book is going to cover HTML5, CSS3 and responsive design.  The titles themselves don't say anything about HTML5 being required for responsive design.

Comment: In 2020 (7 years on) we find the HTML5 grid does away with the need for any media queries. Yes it's possible and extremely simple to create responsive web sites all wrapped in an HTML5 grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media queries were added in [CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Browsers that support CSS3 tend to support reasonable parts of HTML5 so they tend to go together but they are not technically dependent on each other.

If you want to use media queries and then id and class attributes on all of the elements to determine how they resize (or disappear) you are free to however proper semantics in general make styling easier for most people. Also there other benefits besides just styling. Proper semantic markup can help screen readers.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you can create a RWD using ONLY CSS.  You cannot create a RWD using ONLY HTML5.

Comment: @4thSpace Consider yourself corrected, you need HTML **and** CSS (of whatever version) to make anything. HTML without CSS is just plain ugly, and CSS without HTML is a bunch of styling rules for styling... nothing.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I agree HTML is required.  I implied it. But HTML5 is not.

Comment: +1 for reminding folks about accessibility for screen readers.